# Modprobe force=1 on startup

Tags: 22.04, dell, modprobe

How can I run the following command at startup: `sudo modprobe i8k force=1`

This allows me to control the fan speed of my Dell machine and I cannot run it without the `force=1` as it gives an error. I have tried putting `i8k force=1` into `/etc/modules` but that doesn't work.

Is there a way to do what I'm asking or is it impossible?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you remove the faulty setting in `/etc/modules`. Then do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options i8k force=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/i8k.conf
exit
```

Reboot and test.

Answer (score -1):

You can write the configuration under `/etc/modules-load.d/file.conf` then enable the systemd service:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now systemd-modules-load
```

See [modules-load.d](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/modules-load.d.html#), [`man systemd-modules-load`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-modules-load.service.html#).

Also you can write a cron job to execute your command on start-up. Se `man 5 crontab`.